# How do I pass values to another method in class if the array is full in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a complete beginner in Java so I hope I make sense. I want to store values in a class from one method into another method.

If the array is full in the fist class method, I want to add the values into the second method instead which has more space. I check if first method, inFor, is full, then it should add the value of the parameter newCoin into the method moreSpace. So do I call moreSpace inside inFor?

```
 public double inFor(newCoin) {

for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)

 if (arr[i] == null){
  arr[i] = newCoin;

if (i >=arr.length){

  moreSpace(i) //add the values here



 public void moreSpace(){
 String[temp] = new String[arr.length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
temp[i] = arr[i];
 arr = temp;
```

Comment: If you need a variable length array, then use the class `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You could but it would be ugly

```
public double inFor(newCoin) {
        if (i >=arr.length)
          moreSpace(i) //add the values here
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
                if (arr[i] == null)
                    arr[i] = newCoin;
            }
        }
}
```

As mentioned by others use arraylist if you want to work with variable length array. That way you avoid having to increase and decrease size of array unnecessarily. You can still convert them back to an Array at the end of the day anyways

Comment: thank you very much. I am not allowed to use arraylist.

Comment: @buzzyso I see! Best of luck for the assignment!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below as per your requirement but i suggest you to use any dynamic structure which is provided by java like List.

```
public double inFor(String newCoin) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] == null) {
            arr[i] = newCoin;

            if (i >= arr.length) {

                moreSpace(arr, newCoin, i); //add the values here
            }
        }
    }
}

public void moreSpace(String arr[], String newCoin, int i){
    arr[i] = new String(); // arr[i] = new String(newCoin);
    arr[i] = newCoin;      // Not needed if you provid value in construtor like commente code
}
```

Here is your code look like using `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

public double inFor(String newCoin) {

    arr.add(newCoin);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're (badly) reimplementing the functionality that the class `java.util.ArrayList` provides; I suggest you just use that.

Java is 'pass by value': For all non-primitive types (And arrays are not primitive), the value itself is like a treasure, and the variable you have is like a treasure map. So, in: `int[] arr = new int[10];`, the `new int[10];` bit is treasure, and `int[] arr` is a map to the treasure. When you then write, say, `arr = null`, you're taking an eraser to your treasure map. This obviously would do absolutely nothing to the treasure. It's still there. If nobody has a map to it, it is 'lost' (the garbage collector will eventually get around to cleaning up the beach), but if someone else has a copy of your map, they can still get at that array even though you erased your copy.

When you then write `arr = new int[20];` you're creating an entirely new treasure and burying it in the beach someplace, then erasing your treasure map (the one named `arr` - in java, maps have names, treasures do not), and writing an entirely new treasure map on it that leads to your newly created treasure. Just as before, anybody with a copy of the map observes none of this; their copy is not updated, and consequently, if they follow their map they find the old treasure which hasn't changed at all.

Whenever you pass a variable to a method, i.e. you invoke: `moreSpace(arr)`, you're taking your treasure map named 'arr', and making a copy of this map, and you hand the copy to the method. The method is free to mess with their copy and it won't affect you. However, if they follow their map to the treasure and then mess with the treasure, that WILL affect you. Thus, if the moreSpace method does: `arr = new int[20];` you won't notice this, it won't update your view of it. But if the method does: `arr[0] = 10;` you WOULD notice: `obj.foo()` and `obj[foo]` are java-ese for: Follow the treasure map to the treasure, dig down, and act upon the treasure itself.

So, with that as background, how do you 'grow the treasure chest'?

Well, you can't. arrays in java cannot grow or shrink. At all. There are 2 solutions to the dilemma:

1. Have the `moreSpace` method work by creating a new, bigger treasure chest, copying all the bits from the old smaller one over to the new one, and then **returning the map to this new treasure**. Your `moreSpace` method would look like `int[] moreSpace(int[] array)`, not `void moreSpace(int[] array)`, and the invocation to it would be `arr = moreSpace(arr);` (which is updating your `arr` treasuremap to be the new treasure map leading to the new treasure as created by the `moreSpace` method), not simply `moreSpace(arr);`
2. Create an object (a treasure) which contains inside itself a map to another treasure. This way, you can hand a copy of your map to the treasure-containing-a-treasure-map (this is a real Nicolas Cage in National Treasure moment, exciting, isn't it!), and the `moreSpace` map can now create a larger treasure chest and bury it, and then follow the copy of the map it got from you, find that treasure, dig it up, replace the treasure map inside it to the new treasure it made, and then just be done without returning anything.

Option #2 is pretty much precisely what `ArrayList` *is*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using moreSpace, why not use `Arrays.copy()`. It keeps the original contents but reallocates the array.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
int newSize = 10;
arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newSize);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You could always migrate to `ArrayList` but this method is provided for those who wish to use Arrays and still increase the capacity.